# I don’t want to have children, is it haram?

Tags: halal-haram, husband-wife, children

I’m getting to the stage of my life where I’m starting to think about marriage. However, with marriage comes the topic of children. I for one don’t want children and won’t change my mind - I am completely healthy and able to but I’ve never wanted children. Should I find a partner I would of course tell him this from the start and if neither of us want children and I use a contraceptive such as an implant or IUD, is this permissible?

I’ve seen a lot of varying answers so it would be great to get a definite one.

Answer (score -3):

There are some narrations including advice on having children.

Jabir ibn Abdullah reports from the Messenger of God:

“Jabir! Ask Allah for children.” (Bukhari, Marriage, 122)

Ma’qil ibn Yasar reports from the Messenger of God:

“Marry with women who will love their husbands and give them lots of children. I will be proud of your plentifulness against other nations in the day of rising.” (Abu Dawud, Marriage, 3; Nasai, Marriage, 11)

However, it wouldn’t be accurate to evaluate these narrations as a command of God and a duty of women or haram.

Comment: This does nothing to answer the question.